# Change color of elements of a Div using Jquery Hierarchy Selectors

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<div id="parentchild">
    <input id="parentchildbutton" type="button" value="ParentChild" />
    <p><b>Paragraph</b> that have some <b>bolds</b> and <span class="mispan"><b><i>italic</i></b></span> to choose</p> 
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Selector Parent > Child
    $("#parentchildbutton").click(function (event) {
        $("p > b").css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

The thing is, as you can see, the div does not have any class and the idea is to change all the bolds that are in the paragraph of that Div and not the whole page. How can you achieve this? is there any way of select the `div parentchild` so then I can use the Hierarchy Selector Parent > Child?

Comment: Using `next()` https://jsfiddle.net/uxwsb3bp/

Answer (score 1):

The div has an ID that you could use, but you're asking how to traverse up the the nearest div then find those paragraphs.

```
$("#parentchildbutton").click(function (event) {
   $(this).closest("div").find("p > b").css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Nice!, both of you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` variable and `closest()` function to get the parent and then find using your criteria.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Selector Parent > Child
  $("input[value=ParentChild]").click(function(event) {
    $(this).closest('div').find("p > b").css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentchild">
  <input id="parentchildbutton" type="button" value="ParentChild" />
  <p><b>Paragraph</b> that have some <b>bolds</b> and <span class="mispan"><b><i>italic</i></b></span> to choose</p>
</div>
<div id="parentchild1">
  <input id="parentchildbutton2" type="button" value="ParentChild" />
  <p><b>Paragraph</b> that have some <b>bolds</b> and <span class="mispan"><b><i>italic</i></b></span> to choose</p>
</div>
<div id="parentchild2">
  <input id="parentchildbutton3" type="button" value="ParentChild" />
  <p><b>Paragraph</b> that have some <b>bolds</b> and <span class="mispan"><b><i>italic</i></b></span> to choose</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice!, both of you. Thanks